# how to distinguish button in tableviewcell click event and tableviewcell click event

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, button, tableview

I have a button in the tableviewcell. I want to catch the button-click event and cell-click event separately. When the button is clicked, it will cause the button-click event. While other part of the cell is clicked, it will cause the cell-click event.

While the **issue** is when I click the button, the button click event `share` is not executed, but cell selected event is executed.

[image: xib file]
[image: the button]

```
import UIKit

class ArticleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var digest: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var share: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func share(_ sender: Any) {
        print("share")
    }
}
```

Comment: it should behave like that normally. Interactive controls added to `contentView` of the cell override `didSelectCellAt` events. Are you sure you connected the `@IBAction`? maybe you could provide a minimal working example project so that we can test it for you

Comment: 1) which is the value of `User Interaction Enabled` 2) which is the z-order of your button (I see another label might it be above)?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I've connected the `@IBAction`.

Comment: By default button has 30px height, maybe that's why your cell is getting selected. Try to give solid color background to see the frame of the button clearly, make the frame of the button bigger, and make sure that user interaction is enabled, and the button is enabled. If you want to pass a message from cell to view controller when button is tapped, you can use closures with index parameter. And, yeah, check if another view is not covering your button as Andrea suggested.

Comment: @AndreaMugnaini I'm beginner. How can I check these two value.

Comment: Touch the button / Go on "Show the Attributes inspector" / Search in mid page: "Interaction" / There you will find such flag. About the z-order, I think it's enough if you post the nodes hierarchy (left panel of interface builder)

Comment: Thank you Andrea Mugnaini, Fahri Azimov, Milan Nosáľ. You're right, it should behave like that normally. Exclude this doubt, I finally it was caused by the extra constraint setting. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48398170/6521116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I  had thought the issue was caused by the layer sequence. Then with the help of @AndreaMugnaini, @FahriAzimov, @MilanNosáľ, I know the layer sequence was not the issue.

Then I think it may caused by the layout. So I check the constraints, I find there is one extra constraint. I removed the 8.5 constraint, it works well.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can get the click event of whole cell with the `delegate` method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. You have to set the delegate of the table view to the file's owner (Controller).

In order to get the click event of the button, I always do the following work-around. Add a tag to the button as `indexpath.row`. Add target to the button. In the selector function, you can get which cell button is clicked with `sender.tag`.

Comment: you also have to create an outlet of the button. Add the tag and target to that outlet.

Answer (score 2):

> First add delegate and datasource in your controller where you want to use cell.

```
class viewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        // if you want use xib in tableview then open it and add your xib name to replace - ArticleTableViewCell
        //tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ArticleTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ArticleTableViewCell")
    }

    func btn_Handler_Share(sender:UIButton) {
        let selectedIndexpath = sender.tag
        print(selectedIndexpath)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:ArticleTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ArticleTableViewCell") as! ArticleTableViewCell

        cell.share.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.share.addTarget(self,action:#selector(btn_Handler_Share(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(indexPath.row)
    }

}
```

> Remove action of share button into ArticleTableViewCell(UITableViewCell) if exist.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on cell `didSelectRowAt` will called.

For Button event you need to create custom delegate method in your `ArticleTableViewCell` class. like below:

```
import UIKit

protocol ButtonDelegateCell {
    func shareButtonDidPressed()
}

class ArticleTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var digest: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var share: UIButton!

    var delegate: ButtonDelegateCell?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

    @IBAction func share(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.shareButtonDidPressed()
        print("share")
    }
}
```

Now, in `didSelectRowAt` set your delegate like below:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Then implement your delegate method in your ViewController line below:

```
func didButtonPressed() {
        // When you click on Share button this method will called
}
```